# How do I insert Multiple Where Clauses

Tags: sql, where-clause

How would I put multiple where clauses into a SQL statement? Would I use the AND command? I'm not seeing any documentation for this specifically.

Comment: Have you tried to write a `WHERE` clause using an `AND`?

Comment: Yes, I guess AND (which is a logic operator, not a command) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Have you considered reading any documentation for "where" or "and"?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE  Created > 'Jan 1 2012'
AND    FirstName != 'Jim';
```

Answer (score 1):

The where clause uses a predicate, that evaluates to true for each row you are looking for.

When you has the syntax

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE <predicate>;
```

With AND and OR you can combine a predicate for your needs. So the best way to combine your clauses is to use AND/OR.

e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE column1 > 0 AND cloumn2 < 0 ;
```